# Passing async/await callback to sass (C++) crashes randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, async-await

I'm debugging `async/await` code on Node.js 8.4.0. The version #1 works as expected, printing "OK", but version #2 crashes randomly (at least once every 10 runs or so) with errors such as

```
libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!
Abort trap: 6
```

or

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here's my code:

```
var sass = require('node-sass')
var fs = require('fs')

var scss = '@import "foo";'

// Helper function that reads a given file, returning a promise
function readFilePromise(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, (err, buf) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log("ERROR", err)
        reject(err)
      } else {
        resolve(buf)
      }
    })
  })
}

// #1 Pass a normal callback that uses a promise - works as expected.
sass.render({
  data: scss,
  importer: (url, prev, done) => {
    readFilePromise(__filename).then((contents) => {
      done({ contents: '' })
    })
  },
}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err ? err : "OK")
})

// #2 Pass async function - crashes.
sass.render({
  data: scss,
  importer: async (url, prev, done) => {
    var contents = await readFilePromise(__filename)
    done({ contents: '' })  
  },
}, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err ? err : "OK")
})
```

My question: Is this a Node.js bug? Sass bug? Or something I do wrong?

Environment: Node.js 8.4 on macOs Sierra, node-sass 4.5.3.

Comment: You're not directly inter-operating with C++ from what I can tell, and neither do you have any C++ code. I think the C++ tag is unfit and should probably be removed.

Comment: In your second example your going to be returing a promise to importer, this will make SASS think it's not an asynchronous callback. If you want to use async / await inside here, I would place inside an anonymous async function.  Then you will be returning undefined as before.

Comment: Another option would also be to contact `Node-sass` and ask the developers if they can check for a thenable, it would then make it async/await compatible and you could do things like ->  `importer: async (url, prev) { return {contents: await readFilePromise(__filename); }`  IOW: no need for the done callback.

Comment: @tambre - Thanks, removed now. (I added the tag because `node-sass` wraps the `libsass` C++ library and I suspect that's where the crash happened. Also, one of the errors I got was `libc++abi.dylib: Pure virtual function called!`. But you are absolutely correct here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure `node-sass` expects the `importer` method to return promise ? Because that's what `async` functions do. Based on [node-sass docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) it seems the lib only works with callback or synchronous implementations of `importer`. Your implementation returns promise immediately and the lib thinks it's a return from synchronous version and tries to continue its work with the promise itself (not with its resolved value).

Comment: Thanks, this is most probably the reason. Earlier I had a more complicated setup, where a promise return *seemed* to actually work, probably due to a bug of my own.